# Combinar transacciones y consultas preparadas

Tags: php, transacciones, prepared-statements

Estoy estudiando el tema de las transacciones y consultas preparadas en PHP. Probando he creado un código para combinar transacciones con consultas preparadas. Seria algo tal que asi (imaginemos que la conexion ya esta establecida mediante PDO):

```
try {

// 1º Preparo la sentencia/as
$queryInsert = "INSERT INTO `usuarios` (`idusuario`, `nombreusuario`, `emailusuario`, `passusuario`) VALUES (NULL, ?, 'afasf@2224', ?)";
$queryDelete = "DELETE FROM `usuarios` WHERE `usuarios`.`idusuario` = ?";

$conexion->beginTransaction(); //2º Comenzamos la transaccion

$PDOstmt = $conexion->prepare($queryInsert); // 3º Preparo la sentencia primera

$nombreUsuario = "nanaki"; //4º Preparo los valores que enlazare con la sentencia
$passUsuario = "final fantasy 7";

$PDOstmt->execute(array($nombreUsuario, $passUsuario)); // 5º ejecuto

//Repito los puntos 3º, 4º y 5º...

$PDOstmt=$conexion->prepare($queryDelete);

$idusuario=13;

$PDOstmt->execute(array($idusuario));

//...Tantas sentencias como tengamos

$conexion->commit();//6º confirmo cambios...

echo "Usuario actualizado";
$PDOstmt->closeCursor();//Cerramos cursor
$conexion = null;
} catch (PDOException $exc) { //Capturo cualquier error

$conexion->rollback();//... o los revierto si hemos capturado algun error

echo "No se ha podido insertar usuario, error: " . $exc->getMessage();

exit();
}
```

El script funciona. Lo que queria saber es si seria correcta esta forma de hacerlo y de combinar transacciones y consultas preparadas.

Un saludo.

Comment: El código parece correcto. Ha de suponerse que en tu conexión PDO tienes habilitado correctamente el modo de `Excepciones` y que tus tablas están en `InnoDB`. Y hay un pequeño detalle que deberías corregir: tu código está capturando solamente excepciones `PDOException`... ¿Y si ocurre una excepción que no sea de ese tipo?  **Ahí debes capturar una `Excepcion`**, así no se te escapará nada, pues las excepciones pueden ser de cualquier tipo. Te recomiendo que [leas este apartado](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#transactions) en phpdelusions.

Comment: Concuerdo con @A.Cedano aunque desconozco si existe la captura de excepción en tu código y no la colocaste o si sencillamente no existe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo del manejo de PDO y prepared statements me parece que está correcta la implementación, sin embargo, me ha llamado la atención varias cosas en tu código y me gustaría darte algunas sugerencias para mejorarlo en general:

**A)** Evita el uso combinado de mayúsculas y minúsculas en variables de php. Sería mejor si utilizas sólo minúsculas para las variables por ejemplo. Esto debido a que la combinación de mayúsculas y minúsculas se utiliza con gran frecuencia es en la declaración de funciones e implementación de clases y objetos. Por lo que genera cierta "ruido" el hecho de que tengas variables regulares escritas de esa forma.

**Ejemplo:** `$PDOstmt` sería mejor así `$pdostmt`

**B)** Con respecto a esta línea de código:

```
$queryDelete = "DELETE FROM `usuarios` WHERE `usuarios`.`idusuario` = ?";
```

Desconozco si tienes alguna tabla de **"históricos"** o algún **método diario de respaldo** de base de datos pero aún así puedo decirte que no es buena práctica borrar datos **"sensibles"** directamente de una **base de datos**. Es mejor tener un campo "estatus" en la base de datos que indique si está o no activo el usuario en cuestión.

```
$queryDelete = "Update `usuarios` SET estatus_usuario=? WHERE `usuarios`.`idusuario` = ? ";
```

estatus_usuario podría ser un character de longitud 1 que contenga:

**"A"** Para indicar que el usuario esta activo

**"E"** Para indicar que el usuario esta inactivo o "eliminado"

**"B"** Para indicar que el usuario esta baneado (por cierto periodo o quizás permanentemente)

El actualizar el registro en la tabla en vez de eliminarlo verdaderamente se hace por dos cosas:

**1)** normalmente si ocurre un hackeo en la cuenta del usuario "x" este usuario requerirá la atención del soporte técnico y será muy complicado intentar recuperar una cuenta de la cual se ha eliminado los datos de usuarios de la base de datos.

**2)** Que sucede si un usuario elimina su **"cuenta"** y quiere retomarla luego? por ejemplo en 1 o 2 meses después de que la **"eliminó"** (pasa más de lo que imaginas), en este caso le estás negando la oportunidad al **usuario** de retomar el juego y te estás negando la posibilidad de que se convierta nuevamente en un **"cliente"**

**C)** Te recomendaría usar algún hash para las **contraseñas de usuario** (al momento de guardarlas en la bd etc) ya que esto **"blinda"** un poco mejor tu sistema ante cualquier posible **"ataque"** para obtener datos sensibles.

Espero te sea de utilidad mis observaciones. Un Saludo!

Answer (score 2):

Para las transacciones en PDO hay que tener en cuenta lo siguiente:

1. Que las tablas estén en `InnoDB`. Las transacciones no funcionan en tablas `MyISAM`
2. Que el objeto PDO que usas tenga el modo de errores correctamente configurado, teniendo establecido `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` al momento de crear la conexión o estableciéndolo después de haberla creado y antes de proceder a las transacciones. Por ejemplo: `$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`
3. En el `catch`, en vez de capturar solamente una `PDOException`, debes capturar cualquier excepción, poniendo `Exception` en vez de `PDOException`. Supongamos que estás leyendo los datos a insertar de un archivo y hay un fallo de lectura de ese archivo, dicho fallo no será notificado como un `PDOException`, el código no entrará en el `catch` y el `rollBack()`  no podrá realizarse.
4. Si vas a usar `throw`, debes hacerlo después del `rollBack()`, jamás antes de él.
5. Debes asegurarte de en las consultas de la transacción no hay sentencias DDL (Data Definition Language - Lenguaje de Definición de Datos) que definan o modifiquen el esquema de la base de datos, ya que dichas consultas generarán un `commit` implícito. Para más detalles sobre esto [puedes consultar la documentación](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/implicit-commit.html).

Answer (score 0):

Mi gracias por las respuestas, aprendo un monton con las respuestas que me dais. Voy por partes. 
Para la conexion como me indicais si tengo configurado el modo de errores (al menos eso creo) este seria el codigo que uso para la conexion pdo.

```
function conexion()
{
//Variables para la conexion
$host = "localhost";
$nombreBaseDatos = "pruebas";
$password = "";
$usuario = "root";
try{     
$conexion=new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$nombreBaseDatos",$usuario,$password); 
$conexion->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
$conexion->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
return $conexion;
} catch (Exception $ex) {
die("error" .$ex->getMessage());
}
};
```

Las tablas de que uso si son InnoDB.

Me apunto lo de capturar cualquier tipo excepción usando Exception en vez de PDOException.

Huskie, me apunto tambien lo de las variables en minúsculas y los del respaldo de la base de datos. En este caso es solo de prueba y ejemplo y no tengo ningun histórico, pero me lo apunto. Para lo del hash he probado a usar md5. En este caso al ser de prueba tampoco me influye mucho. Gracias Huskie.

Voy a seguir probando y aprendiendo.

Un saludo a todos.

Comment: De nada @Carlosrayon me alegra que la información fue útil. Éxito con tu proyecto!