# PHP MySQL Multiples Querys

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Tengo el siguiente código donde ejecuto 3 Updates, lo extraño es que al ejecutarlo no aparece ningún error, es decir que lo ejecuta todo bien, pero al consultar la BD no hizo ningún cambio, y si quito 2 Querys y solo dejo 1 allí si aplica los cambios.

```
<?php 
   $GLOBALS['conexion']->beginTransaction(); 

                    //NRO FISCAL #1
                    $query = "
                        UPDATE denominaciones
                        SET 
                        singular = 'RTN',
                        plural = 'RTN'
                        WHERE id_denominacion = 6;
                    ";

                    //NRO FISCAL #2
                    $query .= "
                        UPDATE denominaciones
                        SET 
                        singular = 'SAG',
                        plural = 'SAG'
                        WHERE id_denominacion = 7;
                    ";

                    //IMPUESTO
                    $query .= "
                        UPDATE denominaciones
                        SET 
                        singular = 'ISV',
                        plural = 'ISV'
                        WHERE id_denominacion = 8;
                    ";

                    $resultado_denom = $GLOBALS['conexion']->query($query);
                    if($resultado_denom){

                        print "info|Datos Procesados";
                        $GLOBALS['conexion']->commit();

                    }else{
                        print "error|Error al actualizar denominaciones";
                        $GLOBALS['conexion']->rollback();                           
                    }

   $GLOBALS['conexion']->closeCursor(); 
?>
```

Nota: Al realizar la conexión con la BD tengo la siguiente configuración para permitir múltiples Querys, y aun así no funciona.

```
            $this->conexion = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;port=$port;dbname=$db;charset=utf8",$user,$pw,
            array( 
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY => true
            )
        );
```

Comment: En tu caso ¿[se cumplen estas condiciones](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/135444/29967)?  Si no se cumplen no podrás usar transacciones. Si es posible revisa el log de errores, te informará con más detalle de lo que pueda estar ocurriendo. También, tradicionalmente, las transacciones se manejan dentro de bloque `try ... catch` no con un simple `if`

Comment: @A.Cedano gracias por la respuesta estimado, todas esas condiciones las cumplo, sin embargo cambié el IF por el TRY... CATCH y aun así lo aparece ningún error

Comment: Edita la pregunta poniendo el código como lo tienes ahora. Lo puedes comparar [con el ejemplo de phpdelusions](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#transactions), que está bastante completo y bien explicado.